# Store JSON on IOS device

Tags: ios, json, cocoa-touch, nsdictionary, segue

I am building an application that recovers JSON data (1000-2000 lines) from a website. It's basically just a bunch of arrays and values, nothing fancy. What would be the best way to store this information and use it between the views? Should I create a local sqlite database, write to file or just send the information from view to view using prepareforsegue?

I would think the latter is faster and easier to implement, but I'm not sure if it's easier to use after (I'm new to IOS).

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `Core Data` with [Magical Record](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord). It easily maps your JSON objects into `NSObjects` which are then persisted into Core Data. It is thread safe and very powerful.

Or you can map it yourself into `NSObjects` of your choice without actually persisting them or saving them anywhere which is much easier in some cases. It is a good way to go as well.

Answer (score 0):

Both methods looks OK . Now it depends whether your JSON data is big enough to slow down the app.

Answer (score 0):

Sqlite Database is easy to implement to store large information in your app.but if you want to increase performance of app to access data locally you can use core data to store data because it providing object relationship to store data in app that is easy to access and store data.but now it is depends on you